# listas multiple en formulario vba excel

Tags: listbox, excel-2010

solicito su apoyo para poder crear una lista de selección múltiple a la cual le pueda cambiar los valores me explico,
estoy creando un formulario con vba en el cual muestro los datos de mi tabla en una lista y quiero que al seleccionar varios elementos de mi lista pueda cambiar el valor de una columna,
por ejemplo esta es la tabla que se muestra en mi lista del formulario

```
nombre | apellido |id
pepe   | zarate   | 2
juan   | perez    | 1
ismael | guzman   | 3
```

Al yo seleccionar a pepe y a juan, pueda cambiar su id por un 0 y de como resultado

```
nombre | apellido | id
pepe   | zarate   | 0
juan   | perez    | 0
ismael | guzman   | 3
```

lo que tengo hasta ahorita es unicamente los botonos que seleccionan tdodos los registros  y un boton que deselecciona falta construir el boton  editar pero justo es ahi donde ya no se como realizarlo

dejo parte de mi código realizado

```
' boton que selecciona todas los registros
Private Sub btnall_Click()
Dim r As Integer
    For r = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        ListBox1.Selected(r) = True
    Next r
End Sub

' boton que deselecciona los registros seleccionados
Private Sub btnnone_Click()
Dim r As Integer
    For r = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        ListBox1.Selected(r) = False
    Next r
End Sub

' boton ok
Private Sub btnok_Click()

Dim RowRange As Range
Dim RowCnt As Integer, r As Integer
RowCnt = 0
For r = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(r) Then
        RowCnt = RowCnt + 1
    If RowCnt = 1 Then
        Set RowRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(r + 1)
    Else
        Set RowRange = _
        Union(RowRange, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(r + 1))
    End If
End If
Next r
If Not RowRange Is Nothing Then RowRange.Select
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Hola. Por favor, pon el código que has intentado y dónde te está fallando

Comment: Ya pude decirle que  la fila seleccionada le cambie el valor pero al momento que cambia el valor deselecciona las demás  dejo el código
For i = 0 To Me.lst1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.lst1.MultiSelect.Selected(i) = True Then
        'buscar l amanera de cambiar las celdas seleccionadas sin que te las deseleccione cuando haces el cambio Me.lst1.Selected(i)
         Range("a" & i + 2) = Me.cmbvalores.Value
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Comment: En tiempo de ejecución no puedes editar el Listbox porque está bloqueado. Pero esos datos que cargas saldrán de algún sitio. Tienes que modificar la fuente que alimenta al Listbox y recargarlo, no editar el Listbox como tal.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, lo que hice fue gauradar los valores en celdas y despues buscar por un id y que me trajaera el numero de la columna, para despues modificar los datos con un cuadro combinado dentro de la userform, muchas gracias por el apoyo